# Get a java.lang.LinkageError: ClassCastException when use spark sql hivesql on yarn

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

This is the driver i upload to yarn-cluster:

```
package com.baidu.spark.forhivetest

import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
object ForTest {
  def main(args : Array[String]){
  val sc = new SparkContext()
  val sqlc = new SQLContext(sc)
  val hivec = new HiveContext(sc)
  hivec.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS newtest (time TIMESTAMP,word STRING,current_city_name STRING,content_src_name STRING,content_name STRING)")
  val schema = hivec.table("newtest").schema
  println(schema)
  }
```

In hive config file: i set the `hive.metastore.uris` and `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir`

On spark-sumbit I do added jars

- datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar
- datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar
- datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar

Even if I added the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar` and `spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/guava-14.0.1.jar` , I still get this error!

**But when i run this spark on ide it works successly!**

Hope someone can help me ! thx a lot!

This is the error information:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: ClassCastException: attempting to castjar:file:/mnt/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/18/spark-assembly-1.6.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.classtojar:file:/mnt/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/18/spark-assembly-1.6.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.class
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:116)
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:91)
    at javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.<clinit>(MediaType.java:44)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.MediaTypes.<clinit>(MediaTypes.java:64)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBodyFactory.java:182)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBodyFactory.java:175)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:162)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.init(Client.java:342)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.access$000(Client.java:118)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:191)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:187)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:187)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.TimelineClientImpl.serviceInit(TimelineClientImpl.java:268)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.hooks.ATSHook.<init>(ATSHook.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.hooks.HookUtils.getHooks(HookUtils.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.getHooks(Driver.java:1309)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.getHooks(Driver.java:1293)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1347)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1059)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1049)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$runHive$1.apply(ClientWrapper.scala:484)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$runHive$1.apply(ClientWrapper.scala:473)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$withHiveState$1.apply(ClientWrapper.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.liftedTree1$1(ClientWrapper.scala:226)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.retryLocked(ClientWrapper.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.withHiveState(ClientWrapper.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.runHive(ClientWrapper.scala:473)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.runSqlHive(ClientWrapper.scala:463)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.runSqlHive(HiveContext.scala:605)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.HiveNativeCommand.run(HiveNativeCommand.scala:33)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$.apply(DataFrame.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:817)
    at com.baidu.spark.forhivetest.ForTest$.main(ForTest.scala:12)
    at com.baidu.spark.forhivetest.ForTest.main(ForTest.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:542)
16/03/22 17:04:32 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 15, (reason: User class threw exception: java.lang.LinkageError: ClassCastException: attempting to castjar:file:/mnt/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/18/spark-assembly-1.6.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.classtojar:file:/mnt/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/18/spark-assembly-1.6.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.class)
```

Comment: Any resolution for the same?

Comment: any  news about that?

Comment: Reference1: https://community.smartbear.com/t5/Ready-API-and-SoapUI-PlugIn/Got-Error-of-ClassCastException-any-special-annotations-for/m-p/103803#M97

Comment: Reference2: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/101145/spark-job-failure-with-javalanglinkageerror-classc.html

Answer (score -1):

This has to do with your class path. Try not to build a fat jar.