# ClassCastException on Drop table query in apache spark hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

I'm using the following hive query :

```
this.queryExecutor.executeQuery("Drop table user")
```

and am getting the following exception :

```
java.lang.LinkageError: ClassCastException: attempting to castjar:file:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.1.2.4.2.0-258-hadoop2.7.1.2.4.2.0-258.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.classtojar:file:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.1.2.4.2.0-258-hadoop2.7.1.2.4.2.0-258.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.class
at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:116)
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:91)
    at javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.<clinit>(MediaType.java:44)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.MediaTypes.<clinit>(MediaTypes.java:64)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBodyFactory.java:182)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBodyFactory.java:175)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:162)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.init(Client.java:342)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.access$000(Client.java:118)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:191)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:187)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:187)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.TimelineClientImpl.serviceInit(TimelineClientImpl.java:340)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.hooks.ATSHook.<init>(ATSHook.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.hooks.HookUtils.getHooks(HookUtils.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.getHooks(Driver.java:1309)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.getHooks(Driver.java:1293)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1347)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1059)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1049)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$runHive$1.apply(ClientWrapper.scala:495)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$runHive$1.apply(ClientWrapper.scala:484)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$withHiveState$1.apply(ClientWrapper.scala:290)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.liftedTree1$1(ClientWrapper.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.retryLocked(ClientWrapper.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.withHiveState(ClientWrapper.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.runHive(ClientWrapper.scala:484)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.runSqlHive(ClientWrapper.scala:474)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.runSqlHive(HiveContext.scala:613)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.DropTable.run(commands.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$.apply(DataFrame.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:817)
    at com.accenture.aa.dmah.spark.core.QueryExecutor.executeQuery(QueryExecutor.scala:35)
    at com.accenture.aa.dmah.attribution.transformer.MulltipleUserJourneyTransformer.transform(MulltipleUserJourneyTransformer.scala:32)
    at com.accenture.aa.dmah.attribution.userjourney.UserJourneyBuilder$$anonfun$buildUserJourney$1.apply$mcVI$sp(UserJourneyBuilder.scala:31)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:141)
    at com.accenture.aa.dmah.attribution.userjourney.UserJourneyBuilder.buildUserJourney(UserJourneyBuilder.scala:29)
    at com.accenture.aa.dmah.attribution.core.AttributionHub.executeAttribution(AttributionHub.scala:47)
    at com.accenture.aa.dmah.attribution.jobs.AttributionJob.process(AttributionJob.scala:33)
    at com.accenture.aa.dmah.core.DMAHJob.processJob(DMAHJob.scala:73)
    at com.accenture.aa.dmah.core.DMAHJob.execute(DMAHJob.scala:27)
    at com.accenture.aa.dmah.core.JobRunner.<init>(JobRunner.scala:17)
    at com.accenture.aa.dmah.core.ApplicationInstance.initilize(ApplicationInstance.scala:48)
    at com.accenture.aa.dmah.core.Bootstrap.boot(Bootstrap.scala:112)
    at com.accenture.aa.dmah.core.BootstrapObj$.main(Bootstrap.scala:134)
    at com.accenture.aa.dmah.core.BootstrapObj.main(Bootstrap.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ScalaClassLoader.scala:71)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:139)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:71)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:139)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner$class.run(ObjectRunner.scala:28)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.run(ObjectRunner.scala:45)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner$class.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:35)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:45)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:74)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:96)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:105)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

I saw there have been similar posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37009683/spark-hive-java-lang-linkageerror) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36150691/get-a-java-lang-linkageerror-classcastexception-when-use-spark-sql-hivesql-on-y) but they haven't had any response till now. 
Also have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823844/java-lang-linkageerror-classcastexception) but don't think thats a valid course of action in my case.

Whats intriguing is that this is specific when we try to use drop table (or drop table if exists) query.

Hoping to find resolution for the same.

Comment: do you have any answer for this issue?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: @Edge7 Hi, No...we were not able to get a fix for this. As it turned out, the requirement of deleting the table was phased out so wasn't able to do any more research on this.

Comment: very strange error! I am getting the some with Spark 1.6, but with Spark 2.0 the error disappears!

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, The above error could be because of sample class with same package structure ie: 'javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate' found in different JARs issue. Class Objects are created and casted at run time. So there is every possibility the the code responsible for triggering DROP syntax , the above class would be used and broken due as it it is found more than once in the classpath.

I have tried DROP and DROP IF EXISTS in chd5 and was working without issue, below are the details of my run:

first run - Hadoop version - 2.6,Hive 1.1.0 and Spark - 1.3.1  (included hive libraries to spark lib)
second run -Hadoop version - 2.6,Hive 1.1.0 and Spark - 1.6.1 
Mode of run - cli

```
scala> sqlContext.sql("DROP TABLE SAMPLE");
16/08/04 11:31:39 INFO parse.ParseDriver: Parsing command: DROP TABLE SAMPLE
16/08/04 11:31:39 INFO parse.ParseDriver: Parse Completed
......
scala>sqlContext.sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SAMPLE");
16/08/04 11:40:34 INFO parse.ParseDriver: Parsing command: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SAMPLE
16/08/04 11:40:35 INFO parse.ParseDriver: Parse Completed
.....
```

If Possible please validate DROP commands using a different version of spark lib to narrow down problem scope.

Meanwhile, I am analyzing the jars to find out the linkage where two occurrences of same class 'RuntimeDelegate' existence and will report back to check if the removal of any jar can fix the issue and addition of the jar should recreate the same issue.

Comment: Also , if possible please list down the Jersey and javax.ws.rs-api jar references in your environment for benefit of doubt